# Vim - quickfix window size issue (ack.vim)

Tags: vim, terminal, grep, ack

I'm using [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim). It's working finely, except a quickfix window's stange behavior.

After searching done, I can open a file from the results listed on quickfix window.
There are several ways to open. Usualy i go with typing `o` (Open), `v` (Vertical Split) or  `h` (Horizontal Split).
But everytime, either `v` or `h` is pressed, the quickfix window gains height of window.
So if i pressed `h` for five times, terminal is almost to be oqupied by only the quick fix window.
For now, for this workaround, i'll type `ctrl`+`w` `-` to reduce the window height, but this is very annoying.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Those mappings are created by the plugin, as explained in the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/blob/master/doc/ack.txt#L113).

You could disable them by adding the following to your vimrc:

```
let g:ack_apply_qmappings = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, what i want to do is not to disable the keymapping, but stop the annoying height changes. Anyway, your link was quite helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)  If you want to customize the mappings, you should create a dict named `g:ack_mappings` in your vimrc and adapt the default mappings described at the documentation.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is helpful. The problem is with making multiple splits from the quickfix screen which incorrectly enlarges the size of the quickfix window itself.  The OP wants to use the plugin's mappings, just not have the quickfix window enlarged.  Consider posting this query on Ack.vim github.

Answer (score 0):

This is an bug in Ack.vim. See the details of the issue: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/issues/150
There is a fix for this, but it requires using a different github branch of the source (until it is merged back into master):   https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/tree/preserve-list-size